# What is the maximum number of keyspaces in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

What is the maximum number of keyspaces allowed in a Cassandra cluster? The [wiki page on limitations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations) doesn't mention one. Is there such a limit?

Comment: How many keyspaces you need? Cassandra uses a lot of memory, so it is probably going to run out of memory very soon, if you start adding dynamically multiple keyspaces all the time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A keyspace is basically just a Map entry to Cassandra...  you can have as many as you have memory for.  Millions, easily.

ColumnFamilies are more expensive, since Cassandra will reserve a minimum of 1MB for each CF's memtable: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-0-performance

Comment: Thanks for an answer from the project chair!

Comment: Can Cassandra be configured to deallocate that memory for inactive column families? If not, would that be hard to implement?

Comment: For any one checking it now, Cassandra now supports off heap for storing memtables.

Comment: So it is problematic either way since a keyspace is not unlikely to include at least one `ColumnFamily`... Andrew's question is thus quite a propos.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to : https://community.datastax.com/questions/12579/limit-on-number-of-cassandra-tables.html

> We recommend a maximum of 200 tables total per cluster across all
> keyspaces (regardless of the number of keyspaces). Each table uses 1MB
> of memory to hold metadata about the tables so in your case where 1GB
> is allocated to the heap, 500-600MB is used just for table metadata
> with hardly any heap space left for other operations.

> It is a recommendation and there is no hard-limit on the number of tables you can create in a cluster. You can create thousands if you were so inclined.

> More importantly, applications take a long time to startup since the
> drivers request the cluster metadata (including the schema) during the
> initialisation/discovery phase. Retrieving the schema for 200 tables
> is significantly less than it would take to load 500, 1000 or 3000.
> This may not be important to you but there are lots of use cases where
> short startup times are crucial, most notably for short-lived
> serverless functions where execution time costs money and reducing
> execution where possible results in thousands of dollars in savings.