# Cassandra database design - 1000 columns or dynamically created tables

Tags: cassandra

I wanted to hear your advice about a potential solution for an advertise agency database.

We want to build a system that will be able to track users in a way that we know
what they did on the ads, and where.

There are many type of ads, and some of them also FORMS, so user can fill data.
Each form is different but we dont want to create table per form.

We thought of creating a very WIDE table with 1k columns, dozens for each type, and store the data.

In short:

1. Use Cassandra;
2. Create daily tables so data will be stored on a daily table;
3. Each table will have 1000 cols (100 for datetime, 100 for int, etc).

Application logic will map the data into relevant cols so we will be able to search and update those later.

What do you think of this ?

Comment: An immediate thought is that you need to be thinking about how you are going to query the data rather than how you are going to store it.

Comment: querying the data basedon forms fields. think like it is a form builder, eachform different, so query vary..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with generating tables dynamically in Cassandra. You will start to have problems when you have too many tables because there is a per table memory overhead. Per [Jonathan Ellis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256881/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-keyspaces-in-cassandra):

> Cassandra will reserve a minimum of 1MB for each CF's memtable: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-0-performance

Even daily tables are not a good idea in Cassandra (tables per form is even worse). I recommend you build a table that can hold all your data and you know will scale well -- verify this with [cassandra-stress](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema).

At this point, heed mikea's advice and start thinking about your access patterns (see Patrick's [video series](http://www.datastax.com/resources/data-modeling)), you may have to build additional tables to meet your querying needs.

**Note:** For anyone wishing for a schemaless option in c*:
https://blog.compose.io/schema-less-is-usually-a-lie/
http://rustyrazorblade.com/2014/07/the-myth-of-schema-less/

Comment: i see, but my forms are vary, no common so a normal  structure doesnt exists.

Comment: At the very least, you should be able to do something like this: create table( form_id uuid, field_name text, field_value text, primary key (form_id, field_name))

Comment: In other words, de-normailze

Comment: This is just an example of the direction you can go in. You can find a happy medium for your specific use case. Consider the use of collections or user defined types if that helps. But be ready to pay a performance penalty for that convenience.

Comment: what do you think of the option i mention above ?

Comment: what do you think of the option i mention above ? 1 table monthly , this table will be very wide, with many many fields so i can use them to fill data with app manage which field is used for what purpose, so dattime fields will be used using datetime fields, etc,,so when i build a dynmic query,,for filtering i can easily retrieve data..

Comment: I mentioned above, daily tables won't scale after a few years. What would your cql table def look like? Can you update the qiestion to include it?